# Problems when i try to use a new places-compat

Tags: java, android

i try to use a new placesApi, i follow this documentation https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#place-picker-deprecation, when i run my app, android studio return this

"**Error: Type com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.lm is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.fm`**"

and this:
"**Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\14155709.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\places-1.0.0.aar\2f69114c5b5de9392ef400dc02f6f031\jars\classes.jar**"

this problem starts when i put this: **implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'**

and this:**implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'**

i need bout implements, i try to search on google but i didn't found noting, pls help me.

this is my gradle project:

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my gradle app:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.motoja.motojapassageiro"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
    //maps places
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
    //google-play
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
    // Required only if Facebook login support is required
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.40.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

These two dependencies might be conflicting each other:

```
// implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0"
```

The places-compat wrapper is ordinary not required - better refactor your code to the new library.